# Executing list of Mono after completing a first Mono

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

Executing list of mono after completing 1 mono.

```
Mono<Project> mono1 = ...;

List<Mono<?>> publishers = new ArrayList<>();
 publishers.add(mono2);
 publishers.add(mono3);
 publishers.add(mono4);
            
if ( publishers.size() > 0 )
   Mono.zip(publishers, res->prj.id);
```

Here, I want to execute list of Mono after completing Mono1.

I can do chaining. But, Is there anyway to do with Mono.zip ...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear what you're after here. What's your goal with using `zip()`? Do you need access to all the elements published by all your monos in the same code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mono1.then(Mono.zip(publishers, res->prj.id));
```

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Let this {@link Mono} complete then play another Mono.
 * <p>
 * In other words ignore element from this {@link Mono} and transform its completion signal into the
 * emission and completion signal of a provided {@code Mono<V>}. Error signal is
 * replayed in the resulting {@code Mono<V>}.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/thenWithMonoForMono.svg" alt="">
 *
 * <p><strong>Discard Support:</strong> This operator discards the element from the source.
 *
 * @param other a {@link Mono} to emit from after termination
 * @param <V> the element type of the supplied Mono
 *
 * @return a new {@link Mono} that emits from the supplied {@link Mono}
 */
public final <V> Mono<V> then(Mono<V> other) {
```

Comment: How to get the Mono1 response inside then?

Comment: Then you need to change it to `flatMap()`

Comment: I need result from mono 1 and then execute Mono.zip. is it possible without a flatmap?

Comment: You want an access to the value and then `zip()`, so what is wrong with a `flatMap()`? Why do you think it is an evil?

Comment: you mean, mono1.flatMap(res -> {return Mono.zip(publishers, res->prj.id) });

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. It is not clear from your question what is `res`, but if it is really an output of `mono1`, then your comment is fully correct.